# Class to manipulate .ini files in php

Tags: php, class, configuration, ini

I've been playing around with a php class I found on the net called [Config Magik](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1726-PHP-Read-and-write-ini-configuration-files.html) that I use to store some info in a INI file but have recently run into some problems when using removeKey. I wanted to know if someone can point me to a similar class that would work as well or better. Or if there is a better way to go about this.

This is my function right now, after playing around with it like crazy, so it is probably very faulty.

```
require_once('class.ConfigMagik.php');
$config = new ConfigMagik('config.ini', true, true);

if(!empty($_GET)){
    if(!is_writeable('config.ini')){
        echo 'Could not write to config.ini';
        return false;
    }
  //if there is no section parameter, we will not do anything.
  if(!isset($_GET['section'])){ 
    echo false; return false;
  } else {
    $section_name = $_GET['section'];
    unset($_GET['section']);     //Unset section so that we can use the GET variable to manipulate the other parameters in a foreach loop.
    if (!empty($_GET)){
      foreach ($_GET as $var => $value){
            echo $var.'='.$_GET[$var].'<br />';
            //Check if said variable $var exists in the section.
        if($config->get($var, $section_name) !== NULL){
            //Set variable value.
          try{
              $config->set($var, $value, $section_name);
              echo 'Setting variable '. $var.' to '.$value.' on section '.$section_name;
          } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Could not set variable '.$var;
                echo $e;
                return false;
          }
        } else {
            echo $var.' does not exist <br />';
        }
      }
    }
    try{
      $section = $config->get($section_name); //Get the entire section so that we can manipulate it.
      echo '<pre>';print_r($section);echo '</pre>';
            foreach ($section as $title=>$value){
        if(!isset($_GET[$title]) && isset($section[$title])){
            try{
            $config->removeKey($title, $section_name);
            echo '<b>'.$title.'</b>: removed <br />';
            } catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
    $config->save();
    //echo $config->toString('HTML');
    echo true;
    return true;
  }
} else { RUN SOME HTML }
```

It basically saves the settings I pass on from the GET parameters and if the parameters are not there it is supposed to delete it. When I get to $config->removeKey($title, $section_name); in the last try catch statement it won't save automatically (as it should), so I tried running $config->save() and I ended up with a ini file that had section = array everywhere. Any advice will be appreciated as I've been learning PHP on the web for the last few weeks so I believe I've got a ways to go.

I have definitely isolated the problem to the $config->save() part, just don't know how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) and [Zend_Config_Writer_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html) in the past and was satisfied with the features. You will have extract the whole library/Zend/Config folder from Zend Framework and make Zend_Exception available though.

Comment: I do not want to say that this is better - but an alternative worth looking into...

Comment: That's interesting. I've read about it, should probably give it a try.

Comment: From what I just saw, it is about 4mbs big at least. My project is at about 1mb or so and I'd like to keep it very light. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As I said - you don't need the whole framework. Just library/Zend/Config, library/Zend/Config.php, library/Zend/Exception.php   < 100kb

Comment: Alright good to know. I ended up finding a fix for my problems and my function now works as expected but I'll keep in mind for next time. The ZEND framework seems to be the consensus.